# Flutter shared prefrences dont save

Tags: flutter, dart, save, sharedpreferences

I made a login system using a django api and now i want the user to be kept logged in. I googled and came accross the shared prefrences library. i tried it in many ways but the data doestn save.
I check the data in my Homepage page and save it after the log in or account registration

Homepage:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '/data/user_data.dart';
import '/pages/auth/auth.dart';

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const Homepage({super.key});

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  void checkLogin(context) async {
    SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});

    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var data = await prefs.getBool('test');
    debugPrint(data.toString());
    if (user_data['email'] == null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder(
          pageBuilder: (context, animation1, animation2) => LoginPage(),
          transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => checkLogin(context));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: SafeArea(child: const Text('homepage')));
  }
}
```

Login function:

```
user_data = apiReturn['user_data'] as Map;
        jwt = apiReturn['tokens'];
        final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setBool('test', true);
```

i replaced all variables with a boolean field called test to check if my variables were the problem but this code doesnt work either

Comment: I followed the attached video and now its working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szOllHT1S7Y

Answer (score 0):

Solution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szOllHT1S7Y
He made a class for handeling everything, i did it myself and now its working, just wanted to let others with the same problem know how to solve it